# Chrome browser (windows 11): how to prevent users to change any color setting

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, group-policy

In one school's computer classroom, it became necessary to prevent any student from changing any color of the Chrome browser. How to do this?
After a web search I found that it would be possible by adding Chrome policies (downloadable from the site) and setting the same appropriately.
This is the article I followed: [Article](https://www.anoopcnair.com/configure-chrome-group-policy-admx-templates/?unapproved=596453&moderation-hash=670bbf79342833bc41602eec0965e825#comment-596453)
My attempt led to an error;

> Could not find an appropriate resource file for file Windows(C:)\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\chrome.adx (error 2); The specified file could not be found.

the same error is displayed for the file: google.admx, two times both.
So the policies for Chrome are not available as would be expected in the Group Policy after instal.
Are there settings or a free app that allows this?

Comment: "My attempt led to an error" -What error? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  The local group policy would is the only way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Instead of opening a new question you should [edit] this question allowing it to be reopened. Only when the question is clear will it be reopened and possibly answered. Questions should have a minimum of grammatical and spelling errors.

Comment: The solution to the error is explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1613733/admx-an-appropriate-resource-file-could-not-be-found-for). It’s likely connected to your language pack if there isn’t a .ADML file that exists for that language

Comment: [Here](https://chromeenterprise.google/download/?sjid=11826936641447667823-NA) are the files you will want to install